# Fallo en el envío de correos mediante SMTP en una API alojada en Azure Web App

Tags: api, email, azure, smtp, tcp

Tengo una API desarrollada en .NET, alojada en Azure (Plan F1 gratis) como una Web API, y a la hora de llamar a aquellas funciones que se encargan de enviar distintos correos, después de enviar correctamente una media de 10 emails aprox. deja de enviarlos.

Concretamente, el error que me aparece es el siguiente:

```
 ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [::ffff:82.223.190.141]:587
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

Respecto a la configuración de SMTP, utilizo el puerto 587, con ssl Activado.

Cabe mencionar que estas funciones se completaban correctamente con la misma configuración en un entorno de servidor local, y este fallo ocurre únicamente con la API alojada en Azure.

¿Existe alguna limitación por parte de Azure que limite dichas peticiones?

He tratado de resolver el problema basándome en esta posible solución:

> https://blog.brooksjc.com/2018/09/18/troubleshooting-smtp-issues-sending-emails-from-azure-web-apps/

Pero al realizar tcpping la primera conexión falla siempre,.

Después, mediante el fragmento de código a probar sugerido en el sitio web mencionado (paso 4), resulta imposible realizar la conexión, ya que muestra este mensaje:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 82.223.190.141:587...
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:14 --:--:--     0* Connection timed out after 15007 milliseconds
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:15 --:--:--     0

* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 15007 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Los Azure App Services tienen un timeout de 230 segundo.

> Si la aplicación web requiere procesamiento en segundo plano, se recomienda usar Azure WebJobs. La aplicación web de Azure puede llamar a WebJobs y recibir una notificación cuando finalice el procesamiento en segundo plano

Fuente: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/troubleshoot/azure/app-service/web-apps-performance-faqs#why-does-my-request-time-out-after-230-seconds